# Pandas skipping the 1st value in the file in red_csv

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, read-csv

I have pipe delimited file abc.csv which the data  `abc|1234|ghje|piou` but has lots of leading and trailing spaces.  I want to add a header to the file `abc.csv`  `col1,col2,col3,col4`.

I am using

```
col_names =['col1','col2','col3','col4]
df = pd.read_csv(utput.csv',names = column_names,sep='|',index_col=None) 
df.to_csv('output1.csv',sep=',',index=False)`enter code here`
```

I see the output1 is being generated. header row seems to be fine but the data is messed up.Below is how I see the data.It is skipping the value in the 1st col and starting from the 2nd.

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
1234,ghje,piou
```

Basically, I want to add the header to the pipe delimited csv so I can use the header as the variable in my script.

```
name = df['col1']
age =df['col2']
```

Please suggest where I am going wrong.